# C++: long to float with decimals?

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I have a function that takes `long` as an argument, and I want it to return that number as a `float` with seven decimals.

This `long` gets in to the function: 631452947, and I want the function to convert it and return this `float`: 63.1452947

How can I do this?

I have tried this:

```
float makeLatLon (long val) {
    float tzt = (float)val/10000000.0;
    return tzt;
}
```

but it does not work.

Comment: Divide the result and return it?

Comment: `float` (using IEEE FP) has only seven digits of precision, while you're expecting nine. This will never work. Use a `double`.

Comment: @larsmans That should be an answer.

Comment: btw. remember that the 'digits of precision' is not just about the "digits after the comma". 12312.31 123123.1 and 1231231 are 7 digs of precision, too. Many people tend to forget about that. `floats` are really quite 'short' here.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl: Thanks, I assumed that the precision was just the digits behind the comma.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seven digits after the comma means nine digits of precision total, and you can only expect seven digits of precision in a `float` on platforms where that's an IEEE 32-bit FP type (practically everywhere). Use a `double`:

```
long n = 631452947;
float f = n / 10000000.f;
double d = n / 10000000.;

std::cout << std::setprecision(9)
          << f << std::endl
          << d << std::endl;
```

On my box, that prints

```
63.1452942
63.1452947
```

So you see that using a `float` causes a round-off error.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @larsmans, but I need to return the double as a number with seven decimals (not just write it to screen). Do you know how to do this? (Sorry for asking a dumb question here..)

Comment: @allegutta: floating point arithmetic doesn't deal in decimals. You may want to return the `long` and handle the division elsewhere.

Comment: is there no way I can "convert" from long to double and return the double with x amount of decimals?

Comment: @allegutta: another solution for you is that you use a vector of char to hold each digit in the long number. Then, it's up to you how to print it out. (I think this one isn't nice, though).

Comment: @allegutta: It's fairly easy to wrap a long in a class that simulates 7 decimals. A common case is money, where a dollar amount is internally stored as a `long long` counting cents. Only when it's printed will a decimal point be inserted, 2 positions before the end, to set the cents apart.

Answer (score 1):

[IEEE-754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) double spec and variants don't ensure you 7 digits being present for any number because of the density of the double not being continuous, so also double is not a good choice here.
You may want to consider to build your fixed precision math working with integers only and using a structure like:

```
typedef struct { int int_part, unsigned long dec_part } myfloat;
```